# Reading table data (card images), with format specifier given, into Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, io, astropy

I am trying to read in a ascii-table into Numpy/Pandas/Astropy array/dataframe/table in Python. Each row in the table looks something like this:

```
  329444.6949     0.0124    -6.0124 3   97.9459 15  32507 303 7 3 4       8 2 7          HDC-13-O
```

The problem is that there is no clear separator/delimiter between the columns, so for some rows there is no space between two columns, like this:

```
  332174.9289     0.0995    -6.3039 3 1708.1601219  30501 30336 333      37 136          H2CO
```

From the web page it says these are called "card images". The information on the table format is described as this:

> The catalog data files are composed of 80-character card images, with
>   one card  image per spectral line.  The format of each card image is: 
>   FREQ, ERR, LGINT, DR,  ELO, GUP, TAG, QNFMT,  QN',  QN"  (F13.4,F8.4,
>   F8.4,  I2,F10.4,  I3,  I7,    I4,  6I2,  6I2)

I would really like a way where I just use the format specifier given above. The only thing I found wasNumpy's genfromtxt function. However, the following does not work.

```
np.genfromtxt('tablename', dtype='f13.4,f8.4,f8.4,i2,f10.4,i3,i7,i4,6i2,6i2')
```

Anyone knows how I could read this table into Python with the use of the format specification of each column that was given?

Comment: How many rows have input data?

Comment: it seems every column has own constant width `FREQ = row[0:13]`, `ERR = row[13:13+8]`, etc

Comment: @jezrael It depends, it can be several thousands of lines/rows long.

Comment: @furas Yes, but I would like to know if there is an easier way, where I could just use the given format specification. If something is changed in the format, I have to go in and change that slicing.

Comment: Not that it matters, but this format and the "card image" nomenclature suggests that it was originally designed to be stored on punch cards.
That said, it's just a fixed width column format as @Tom Aldcroft demonstrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fixed-width reader in Astropy.  See: http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/io/ascii/fixed_width_gallery.html#fixedwidthnoheader.  This does still require you to count the columns, but you could probably write a simple parser for the `dtype` expression you showed.

Unlike the pandas solution above (e.g. `df['FREQ'] = df.data.str[0:13]`), this will automatically determine the column type and give float and int columns in your case.  The pandas version results in all `str` type columns, which is presumably not what you want.

To quote the doc example there:

```
>>> from astropy.io import ascii
>>> table = """
... #1       9        19                <== Column start indexes
... #|       |         |                <== Column start positions
... #<------><--------><------------->  <== Inferred column positions
...   John   555- 1234 192.168.1.10
...   Mary   555- 2134 192.168.1.123
...    Bob   555- 4527  192.168.1.9
...    Bill  555-9875  192.255.255.255
... """
>>> ascii.read(table,
...            format='fixed_width_no_header',
...            names=('Name', 'Phone', 'TCP'),
...            col_starts=(1, 9, 19),
...            )
<Table length=4>
Name   Phone         TCP
str4    str9        str15
---- --------- ---------------
John 555- 1234    192.168.1.10
Mary 555- 2134   192.168.1.123
 Bob 555- 4527     192.168.1.9
Bill  555-9875 192.255.255.255
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I also by sheer chance (looking for other stuff) found out about the package FortranFormat (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fortranformat), there I should be able to just copy the specification into the reading function. I will try it out later and if successful post alternative answer.

Comment: I tried using the fortranformat module now. It is very clunky, I would suggest anyone facing similar problem to just get the width of each string from the format specification and use Astropy Tables (or any other fixed width reader).